# How to process php file on tree child click event?

Tags: php, event-handling, extjs4.2

I have created a **`tree panel`** in the **`Viewport`** and also placed a **`toolbar`** with some **`menu items`** in the north region of **`Viewport`**.

***This is how it works:***

1. I select File -> Open, then I get an i.e. an XML file
2. Now this **`"somefile.xml"`** will dynamically be added to the tree

***I want to do the following on treeChileNodeClick:***

1. Once I **`dblclick`** on `somefile.xml`, I want to be able to call a **`php`** file which does something with the xml file and returns the results
2. How can I run that **`php`** script?
3. How can I retrieve the returned values of that **`php`** script?

Thanks for any tip/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from Sencha website how to do it. Here is for people that are wandering.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "test.php?id=something",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
        Ext.get("result").update(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

If anything needs to be added, please feel free to add.